# Вызвать функцию Python и передать значение

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

```
def town(message):
    if message.text == 'Москва':
        keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True,False)
        keyboard.add('Дружбы Народов')
        keyboard.add('Лубянка')
        keyboard.add('Выхино')
        send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Выберите район', reply_markup=keyboard)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(send,next)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как при клике на кнопку Дружбы Народов, Лубянка или Выхино вызвать функцию `next` и передать в неё к примеру значение 123

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])    
def town(message):
    if message.text == 'Москва':
       keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True,False)
       keyboard.add('Дружбы Народов')
       keyboard.add('Лубянка')
       keyboard.add('Выхино')
       bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Выберите район', reply_markup=keyboard)
        
    elif message.text == 'Лубянка':
         msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'введите текст')
         bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, next)


def next(message):
    print('на предыдущем шаге вы ввели', message.text)
```

UPD:

```
def func(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'введите текст')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, func_2, '123')


def func_2(message, value):
    print(message.text)
    print(value)
```

Comment: Подскажите а как передать не введенный текст в def next, а значение к примеру 123 ?

Comment: дополнил свой ответ. текст так и так прилетит

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, пытаюсь исключить ввод текста и оставить только передачу 123 и у меня выходит ошибка. Как в next передать только 123 без ввода текста ?

Comment: никак, register_next_step_handler ожидает сообщение от пользователя и передаёт в следующий шаг.

Comment: если вам нужно в `next` понять кто вызвал её, вы можете передавать в `value` (из моего дополнения) уникальное значение для шага и через if\elif обрабатывать. так же никто не запрещает вам передавать несколько аргументов - `(msg, next, '123', '456')` и `next(message, value, value1)`

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь